# babel: Unknow option `slovene'

Tags: babel

I would like to know how to install support for language "slovene" in Babel? I am using TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) on Ubuntu 13.10 version, Linux 64-bit.

This question was asked before, but the solution is not working for me. E.g., sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german produces

```
Err http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main texlive-lang-german all 2013.20130722-1   404  Not Found [IP:
193.2.1.88 80]
```

Failed to fetch http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-lang/texlive-lang-german_2013.20130722-1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80] E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

help appreciated. Bojan

Comment: Did you install the `babel-slovenian` package? Btw, you should update to TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I don't use ubuntu, but I am not sure whether such older TL - packages are still available.

Comment: According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/which-ubuntu-version-is-equivalent-to-debian-squeeze the version of Debian corresponding to Ubuntu 13.10 is `wheezy`, which only supports TeX Live 2012. In TL 2012/Debian, Slovenian support is in `texlive-lang-other`, while in TL 2014/Debian it is in `texlive-lang-european`.

Answer (score 2):

You may need Ubuntu package [texlive-lang-european](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=texlive-lang-european) for slovenian support.